# How to restrict user to access website by index.php

Tags: magento-1.9, php

My client don't want home page accessible if someone type www.domain.com/index.php.

He only want home page accessible by domain name only(without index.php).
He thought it is affecting the site SEO

Is it possible? Please suggest guys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls

Have a look here :)

Comment: @LukeRodgers thanks for your comment, I tried using this method but site is still accessible from www.domain.com/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Right after

```
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Put this in your .htaccess file

```
    RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R,L]
```

[UPDATE]Or this:

```
    RedirectMatch 301 index.php/(.*) /$1
```

Must be before:

```
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse... You have to edit ".htaccess" (or a file like that) for it.

You have to ask your system administrator or Google: ".htaccess redirect".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so after doing ".htaccess redirect" site will be not accessible from typing /index.php (www.domain.com/index.php)

Answer (score -1):

Go to `system -> configuration` and *enable* `seo friendly urls` .

`index.php` will be removed.